# Can I configure Prnt-screen key order to be stored in my pictures folder?

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, printing, screenshot, scrot-command

I am currently using Lubuntu 18.04.

When I press Impr-Pant in my keyboard the png archive generated is stored directly in my home folder.

My question is:

Can I configure Print-screen key order to be stored in my pictures folder?

I don't want to install anything like shutter or another programs, I just want to store my print-scr captures in my pictures folder.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @DKBose I read your post and I was able to learn how to do it, thank you so much.

Comment: @DKBose  I did it but I just check and although the shot is stored in my pictures folder as a png file, a duplicate appears in my home folder, so now I have 2 screenshots... may be I didn't erase all the lines I should erase?

Comment: the home folder file is named "2018-10-30-052005_1024x768_scrot.png" and the one in my pictures folder is named 20181030052005.png I thik I didn't make it worked as desired...

Comment: I'll check the file again and try to erase the lines causing the duplicate order, if I am not able to do it, I'll let you know and post it in pastebin, thanks again...

Comment: I put it in pastebin, I think is just as you suggested in your post but let me know when you take a look at it... https://pastebin.com/Cw261x5w

Comment: If I remove those lines no screen shot, so, I put my back up file again in place, I don't know why but didn't work... Thank you so much anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keybindings for "Print" key at

line no. [503](https://pastebin.com/Cw261x5w)

```
<keybind key="Print">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>lxsession-default screenshot</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

and at line no. [508](https://pastebin.com/Cw261x5w)

```
<keybind key="Print">        # Immediate scrot of active window
  <action name="Execute"><command>sh -c 'scrot -u /home/j18/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png'</command></action>
</keybind>
```

are causing duplicate screenshots.

Just remove the one at 503 and screenshots won't show up in your home folder.

Also, you could remove the  "sh -c"

```
<command> scrot -u ~/Pictures/"$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)".png<command>
```

will work just fine.

For the changes to have the effect restart the session or run

```
openbox --reconfigure
```